# Mostrar mensajes de error de una api en laravel blade

Tags: laravel, json, api, blade

Estoy empezando a crear una API con Laravel, sobre la cual tengo una pregunta, desde antes cuando hice las validaciones en el controlador, lo envié así.

```
$rules = [
    'receptor' => 'required',
    'accion' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required',
    'fech_ini' => 'required',
    'fech_fin' => 'required',
];
$message = [
    'receptor.required' => 'Receiver is Required',
    'accion.required' => 'Acción is Required',
    'state.required' => 'State is Required',
    'fech_ini.required' => 'Start Date is Required',
    'fech_fin.required' => 'End Date is Required',
];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$message);
if($validator->fails()):
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->with('message','An error has occurred:')->with('typealert','danger')->withInput();
else:
   //save
endif;
```

y en mi template blade lo mostraba asi

```
<div class="social_media">
 @if (Session::has('message'))
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('typealert') }}" style="display:none;text-align: left;">
    {{ Session::get('message') }}
    @if ($errors->any())
      <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    @endif
    <script>
      $('.alert').slideDown();
      setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert').slideUp(); }, 10000)
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

@endif

pero al hacer una api se hace diferente ya que el error lo manda un json y de esta manera no llego a la respuesta de como mostrar los mensajes en el blade ya que al consumir la api de Session no me funciona
ya que e tratado de mostrarlo de esta manera al hacer una peticion post pero solo me reinicia la pagina y no me muestra los mensajes

```
@if ($errors->any())
   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
         {{ $error }}
     </div>
    @endforeach
 @endif
```

De esta manera hago la validación y envió a través de un json los errores

```
$rules = [
'receptor' => 'required',
'accion' => 'required',
'state' => 'required',
'fech_ini' => 'required',
'fech_fin' => 'required',
];
$message = [
'receptor.required' => 'Receiver is Required',
'accion.required' => 'Acción is Required',
'state.required' => 'State is Required',
'fech_ini.required' => 'Start Date is Required',
'fech_fin.required' => 'End Date is Required',
];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$message);
if($validator->fails()):
return response()->json([
  'validator'=> $validator,
  'message'=> 'An error has occurred',
  'typealert' => 'danger',
]);
else:
//save
endif;
```